# Resgatando a útima inserção no banco com PDO lastInsertId

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Estou tentando resgatar o último `id` no banco com `lastInsertId()` do PDO, mas não aparece nada.

**OBS:** estou utilizando o Postgre.

```
<?php
try {

    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=bancocjweb1', 'postgres', '12345');

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoas (sexo, nascimentodata, email, nome, cpf) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

    try {
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'm',
            '1987-01-01',
            'teste@teste.com',
            'teste',
            '05255178910'
        ));

        $dbh->commit();
        echo $dbh->lastInsertId();

    }
    catch (PDOExecption $e) {
        $dbh->rollback();
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
    }
}
catch (PDOExecption $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Better to use `INSERT ... RETURNING` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/currently/static/sql-insert.html). Sorry, I don't know if there's a translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira prática de retonar o id inserido com o postgres é utilizar a cláusula [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html) basta informar o nome do campo [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html)(que é o equivalente ao auto-increment do mysql) ou nome dela, como comentado pelo Craig Ringer.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoas (sexo, nascimentodata, email, nome, cpf)
                       VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING id ");

$stmt->execute(array('m', '1987-01-01', 'teste@teste.com', 'teste', '05255178910'));
$dbh->commit();
$ultimo_id = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Obrigado, tá puxando certinho o id.

Comment: Lendo as respostas, e concordando com todas, a resposta entregue pelo 'perdeu' irá funcionar para bases de dados Oracle e Postgre como solicitado. No entanto e por se fazer referência ao PDO o método preferencial deverá ser como indicado na resposta do 'papa charlie', dessa forma irá sempre funcionar mesmo sobre
uma base de dados Mysql que não suporta o comando 'RETURNING'

Answer (score 3):

Sem replicar seu código... Execute *lastInsertId* antes de *commit*.
É um caso relatado e você pode [ler aqui no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php#85129).

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt->execute(array( ... ));

    echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
    $dbh->commit();

}
```

Comment: Você consegue pegar o id inserido após o `commit()` passando o nome da sequence em `lastInsertId()`.