# Dificuldades com PHP - lastInsertId()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com dificuldades para conseguir pegar o ultimo id inserido na minha tabela utilizando a função do php PDO `lastInsertId()`
Como faço para conseguir o ultimo id inserido em minha tabela utilizando minha estrutura?

> Conexão com o banco

```
class ConnectionDB{
 private function setConnection(){
   try {
     $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=easyjobapi", "root", "");
     $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $con->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
     return $con;
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Erro ao conectar-se: ".$e->getMessage();
   }
 }
 public function getConnection(){
   return $this->setConnection();
 }
}
```

> Arquivo de teste

```
$con = new ConnectionDB();
/*tabela teste so contem um coluna chamada id AUTO_INCREMENT e a coluna nome*/
$stmt2 = $con->getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO teste (nome) VALUES ('MAX123')");
$stmt2->execute();
var_dump($con->lastInsertId());
```

> Erro apresentado

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ConnectionDB::lastInsertId() in C:\xampp\htdocs\easyjob\api\site\teste.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\easyjob\api\site\teste.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

Já tentei também:

```
$lastId = $con->lastInsertId();
var_dump($lastId);
```

Porém ainda me apresenta o erro:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ConnectionDB::lastInsertId() in C:\xampp\htdocs\easyjob\api\site\teste.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\easyjob\api\site\teste.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

Como proceder?

Comment: O exemplo desta reposta é utilizando uma função do Postgres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cara eu acho que a sua classe de conexao pode estar errada tenta essa

> conexao

```
<?php
class ConnectionDB{
private $conn;  
public function __construct(){
try {
     $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=easyjobapi", "root", "");
     $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $con->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
     $this->conn = $con;

   } catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Erro ao conectar-se: ".$e->getMessage();
   }
 }
 public function getConnection(){
 return $this->conn;
 }
```

}

> teste

```
  $con = new ConnectionDB();
  /*tabela teste so contem um coluna chamada id AUTO_INCREMENT e a coluna nome*/
  $stmt2 = $con->getConnection();
  $stmt2->prepare("INSERT INTO teste (nome) VALUES ('MAX123')");
  $stmt2->execute();
  $las_id = $stmt2->lastInsertId();
  $id = var_dump($las_id);
```

Comment: Vlw pela resposta, eu pensei em fazer assim, mas é que gostaria de utilizar o `lastInsertId()`, pois no meu projeto faço mais de 1 insert e utilizando esse método proposto por voce, não ficaria viável, eu faço a inserção de dados em uma tabela e depois com o id gerado desta tabela faço inserção de dados em outra tabela.

Comment: @MaxRogério sua pergunta já tem a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31138/resgatando-a-%c3%batima-inser%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-banco-com-pdo-lastinsertid)

Comment: @MaxRogério acho que ao inves `var_dump($con->lastInsertId());` deve ser 
`$lastId = $con->lastInsertId()` de depois um var_dump em $lastId

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Desculpe mas não é a minha solução, na resposta é apresetanda a função `returning id`, que no caso do MySql seria `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`, creio eu

Comment: @AdrianoBack, vlw Adriano, mas o erro persiste... Se for possível testar essa minha estrutra, e me auxiliar a como resolver... ficarei agradecido.

Comment: @MaxRogério vou editar minha resposta

Comment: @MaxRogério veja a sua classe acho que ta com algum problema lá

Comment: @AdrianoBack, consegui resolver baseado na sua resposta. Obs: não precisei alterar minha classe. Guardei o retorno da conexão em uma variavél a parte. Como você colocou no exemplo